# Load first item from xamarin sql database in C#

Tags: c#, sql, xamarin

I use helper code below to get the first ID from MyTable but an error.
How should this code be made accessible?

```
public Task<MyTable> GetLastTableItem(int id)
{
    return _db.Table<MyTable>().Where(i => i.ID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Then I want to display it in label.
How should this be made?

```
void GetLastItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Label label = new Label()
  label.Text = bla''bla''bla.GetLastTableItem();
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `error CS1001: Identifier expected`

Comment: can you share more details? stacktrace, line number, etc. more code.

Comment: else looking at your code i can see that you didn't pass the id for calling GetLastTableItem

Comment: in my model like `public class MyTable {[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }}`. is this what you mean? how should the code above work?

Comment: Not your model, your viewmodel

Comment: sorry if it's wrong, I'm still just learning C #.    or suppose I have a MyTable database, then how should the first item of the database be displayed on the label? :)

Comment: First item of database is table and first item of table will be the object you are going to fetch and from that object you can choose the property's value which u want to show to your label.

Comment: if written in C # like what?

Comment: You could get the `MyTable` when you call `GetLastTableItem()`;It's a object,it maybe contains a string type property ,maybe called `Name` or others,then you need to set  `label.Text = bla''bla''bla.GetLastTableItem().Name;`.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT it like this? `label.Text = database.GetLastTableItem().Name;`

Comment: @anoaanoa Yes,you could add the async key word to your method if you use await.Or you could show your complete codes of the page which you want to display the first item from your sql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to display the `Name` property

```
var item = await GetLastTableItem(id);
label.Text = item.Name;
```

Comment: I try like this img .. [link image](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPIzDouVZ6kSCqi9n596_pAXQfAD8hXYcmPCxuH93XaVlEUX1tWE4Z1XfQ9A1BkpQ/photo/AF1QipNprAv3AgDLTTMKrzyttr5CP8ZPeer1wgZvYJVL?key=aTBxM21wWTRVdWFYd0IyY3ZzM3NBRFNVazZUdjlR)

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images.  I have no idea what "red squiggle" means.  It would be much more helpful if you posted the actual error message.

Comment: on my error list result is the name `id` does not exist in the current content, the name `GetLastTableItem` does not exist in current content, the `await` operator can only be used within an async method.

Comment: first, you need to declare and set a value for id before you can pass it.  2nd, I have no idea where your "GetLastTableItem" method is located, you will need to specify the correct instance or class reference for that.  3rd, you need to use async/await if you are using the async SQLite connection.  These are all fairly basic C# issues

Comment: geez ,, this is one mistake that I did not include in my question. about class references. both are from different classes for `GetLastTableItem` I put as` Helper.cs` and for `GetLastItem`  on `EditPage.xaml.cs` page

Comment: then you need an instance of your Helper class in order to call GetLastTableItem.  Again, this is basic C#

Comment: to be honest, i'm still new to C#. but thanks again @jason for the educational response. I will try to find out more in this matter, then convey the results that I did. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below link you will get to know the basics of sqlite like how to fetch first item, getting all items from table, getting item via id, etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases

Comment: if using this, how to call it to display to label.Text `public Task<List<MyTable>> GetItemsNotDoneAsync()
        {
            // return _db.QueryAsync<MyTable>("SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE [Done] = 0");
            return _db.QueryAsync<MyTable>("SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1");
        }`

Comment: I try with `label.Text = App.Dtmytable.GetItemsNotDoneAsync().ToString();` but its output `System.Threading.Task.Task'1[System.Collections.Generic.List'1[MyTables.Models.Mytable]]`

Comment: your DB query returns EVERY column for the db row.  You need to specify **which specific** column you want to display in your Label.

Comment: I have no idea what that is supposed to mean

Comment: sorry @jason, because of the high enthusiasm for learning, I finally forgot to translate my language. :).
For example, I chose column 1. And how then?

Comment: specify which property of your `MyTable` that you want to display.

Comment: from my viewmodel `public class MyTable
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID{ get; set; }
        public int Name { get; set; }
}`